# A problem regarding field theory: determine the fixed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I came across this problem in N. Jacobson's *Basic Algebra* (Vol I):

> Let $E = (\mathbb{Z}/(p))(t)$, where $t$ is trasncendental over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$. Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms generated by the automorphism of $E$ such that $t \rightarrow t+1$. Determine $F$, the fixed field of $E$, and $[E:F]$.

Now, $G$ consists of the elements of the form $t \rightarrow t+i$, where $1\leq i \leq p-1.$ So an element $f(t)/g(t)$ ($g(t) \neq 0)$ is in $F$ iff $f(t)/g(t) = f(t+i)/g(t+i) $ for all such $i$, i.e. $f(t)g(t+i) = f(t+1)g(t)$ for all $1\leq i \leq p-1.$ I'm guessing from here that the elements must be constants. But I can't prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That you couldn't prove a false statement speaks in your favour: see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Did you notice that $t^p-t$ is invariant under $G$ ?